# MultipleObjectsReturned at /contact-agent/ get() returned more than one Property -- it returned 2

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So I am trying to build a website using Django where users can visit a `property-detail` page then contact the property's `agent`. Users need to fill out a form which will then be sent to the `agent` via email. My email is working fine but since `property-detail view` is a class-based view and the `contact_agent view` is a function based view they are different views. So I can't seem to get the `property's agent` dynamically to get the `agent's` email to send him the email.

My models.py:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')


class Property(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    price_per_sqft = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 10000)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    description =  models.TextField()
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent_description = models.TextField()
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.IntegerField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')
```

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def contact_agent(request):
    property = get_object_or_404(Property)
    agent = property.agent
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        current_address = request.POST['current_address']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        message = request.POST['message']

        application = f"Name: {name}\nPhone: {phone}\nEmail: {email}\nCurrent Address: {current_address}\nMessage: {message}"
    
        email_message = EmailMessage(
            f'Message to agent {agent} from {name}',
            application,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            ['{agent.email}'],  
        )
    
        email_message.send()

        return render(request, 'users/contact_agent.html', {
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'phone': phone,
            'current_address': current_address,
        })
    
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {})
```

Comment: Well there are two `Property`s, hence `property = get_object_or_404(Property)` will error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you likely got more than one `Property` in the database. The line:

```
property = get_object_or_404(Property)
```

queries the database to return the `Property`s, and if there is only one item, that is no problem. It will assign that one.

But the problem of course is when there are *multiple* `Property`s. In that case, it thus can not be distinguished.

Likely this worked as long as there was one property. To disambiguate, you normally include the primary key in the path and thus query with that primary key:

```
@login_required
def contact_agent(request, pk):
    property = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=pk)
    # …
```

and in the path:

```
path('contact-agent/<int:pk>/', contact_agent)
```

and thus the view now is something like `contact-agent/2/` where *`2`* is the primary key of the `Property` for which you want to contact the agent.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.